# Move WooCommerce product description below summary in its own div

Tags: php, wordpress, function, woocommerce

So I am trying to move the product description "proddesc" outside of the "summary entry-summary" div and below that same div. Right now it's inside the "summary entry-summary" and i want it to be outside of that. if that makes sense.

[image]

This is where its at right now

```
<div class="single-product-summary">
 <div class="summary entry-summary">
   <div class="woocommerce-product-details__short-description"></div>
   <div class="product_meta"></div>
   <div class="proddesc"></div>
  </div>
 </div>
```

and i would like it like this

```
<div class="single-product-summary">
 <div class="summary entry-summary"> 
   <div class="woocommerce-product-details__short-description"></div>
   <div class="product_meta"></div>
 </div>
 <div class="proddesc"></div>
</div>
```

So i used this function in my functions.php file

```
function woocommerce_template_product_description() {
    echo '<div class="proddesc">';
    wc_get_template( 'single-product/tabs/description.php' );
    echo '</div>';
  }
    add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_product_description', 60 );
```

which does the job on taking it out of the original location but I need it to be placed inside

```
  <div class="single-product-summary">
```

and not inside

```
   <div class="summary entry-summary">
```

hopefully this all makes sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So thankfully i goolged a bit more and i realized that i put the wrong hook in my functions.

it should be

```
function woocommerce_template_product_description() {
echo '<div class="proddesc">';
wc_get_template( 'single-product/tabs/description.php' );
echo '</div>';
 }
 add_action( 'woocommerce_after_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_product_description', 60 );
```